# How to add hours to current date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to add hours to current time like

```
-- NOT A VALID STATEMENT
-- SELECT GetDate(DATEADD (Day, 5, GETDATE()))
```

How can I get hours ahead time in SQL Server?

Comment: [`DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) so... `declare @num_hours int; set @num_hours = 5; select dateadd(HOUR, @num_hours, getdate()) as time_added, getdate() as curr_date`

Answer (score 156, accepted):

[DATEADD (datepart , number , date )](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
declare @num_hours int; 
    set @num_hours = 5; 

select dateadd(HOUR, @num_hours, getdate()) as time_added, 
       getdate() as curr_date
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Select JoiningDate ,Dateadd (day , 30 , JoiningDate)
from Emp

Select JoiningDate ,DateAdd (month , 10 , JoiningDate)
from Emp

Select JoiningDate ,DateAdd (year , 10 , JoiningDate )
from Emp

Select DateAdd(Hour, 10 , JoiningDate )
from emp


Select dateadd (hour , 10 , getdate()), getdate()

Select dateadd (hour , 10 , joiningDate)
from Emp


Select DateAdd (Second , 120 , JoiningDate ) , JoiningDate 
From EMP
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer! Explain how this code can be useful

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **mySql** or similar SQL engines then you can use the `DATEADD` method to add hour, date, month, year to a date.

```
select dateadd(hour, 5, now());
```

If you are using **postgreSQL** you can use the `interval` option to add values to the date.

```
select now() + interval '1 hour';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @hours int = 5;

select dateadd(hour,@hours,getdate())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

The DATEADD() function adds or subtracts a specified time interval from a date.

```
DATEADD(datepart,number,date)
```

datepart(interval) can be hour, second, day, year, quarter, week etc;
number (increment int);
date(expression smalldatetime)

For example if you want to add 30 days to current date you can use something like this

```
 select dateadd(dd, 30, getdate())
```

To Substract 30 days from current date

```
select dateadd(dd, -30, getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT GETDATE() + (hours / 24.00000000000000000)
```

Adding to GETDATE() defaults to additional days, but it will also convert down to hours/seconds/milliseconds using decimal.