# How to add hours to work day in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have seen many example adding working date (business days) to date in SQL. But I would like to add hour.

For example; I would like to add 36 hour to date not in Sunday , Saturday
Could one help me about it ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddWorkDays 
(    
    @WorkingDays As Int, 
    @StartDate AS DateTime 
) 
RETURNS DateTime 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count AS Int
    DECLARE @i As Int
    DECLARE @NewDate As DateTime 
    SET @Count = 0 
    SET @i = 0 

    WHILE (@i < @WorkingDays) --runs through the number of days to add 
    BEGIN
-- increments the count variable 
        SELECT @Count = @Count + 1 
-- increments the i variable 
        SELECT @i = @i + 1 
-- adds the count on to the StartDate and checks if this new date is a Saturday or Sunday 
-- if it is a Saturday or Sunday it enters the nested while loop and increments the count variable 
           WHILE DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(d, @Count, @StartDate)) IN (1,7) 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @Count = @Count + 1 
            END
    END

-- adds the eventual count on to the Start Date and returns the new date 
    SELECT @NewDate = DATEADD(d,@Count,@StartDate) 
    RETURN @NewDate 
END
GO
```

Comment: @JamesZ Business days. days which is not included holiday (Sunday,Saturday)

Comment: You should most likely create a calendar table that contains info about holidays. For example row for each possible day and info if it's holiday or not. Otherwise the code is going to be really complex.

Comment: You might want to ponder a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression using the weekday to determine how many hours to add to the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will add N hours to a date (excluding Saturday and Sundays).

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 datetime = '2017-04-28'
Declare @Hours int  = 36

Select D=max(D)
 From  (
        Select D,HN=-1+Row_Number() over (Order by D)
         From  (Select D=DateAdd(HOUR,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (select null)),@Date1) From  master..spt_values n1 ) D
         Where DateName(WEEKDAY,D) not in ('Saturday','Sunday') 
       ) D1
 Where HN=@Hours
```

**Returns**

```
2017-05-01 12:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

is it what you are looking for?

```
declare @num_hours int; 
    set @num_hours = 1; 

select dateadd(HOUR, @num_hours, getdate()) as time_with_hour;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @num_hours int; 
set @num_hours = 5; 

select dateadd(HOUR, @num_hours, getdate()) as time_added, 
   getdate() as curr_date
```

This question is already answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518290/how-to-add-hours-to-current-date-in-sql-server)