# Split time in time out records that fall between night shifts

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am very new to SQL Server and I am trying to split time in time out records that fall between night shifts from a employee shifts table but I am having a difficult time doing so. Night shift runs from 10pm to 7am

Example below might help make things clearer.

E.g

```
EmployeeId   InTime                     OutTime                  
----------   -----------------------    ----------------------- 
1            2018-08-10 21:00:00.000   2018-08-11 09:00:00.000
```

Desired Output

```
EmployeeId   InTime                     OutTime                   Type
----------  -----------------------    -----------------------   -------
1            2018-08-10 21:00:00.000    2018-08-10 22:00:00.000   day
1            2018-08-10 22:00:00.000    2018-08-11 07:00:00.000   night
1            2018-08-11 07:00:00.000    2018-08-11 09:00:00.000   day
```

Code for current table:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
    (
        EmployeeId INT,
        InTime DATETIME,
        OutTime DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @tbl (Employee_Id, Shift_Start, Shift_end) 
VALUES (1, '2018-08-10 21:00:00.000', '2018-08-11 09:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Hi, Zeena You can use dateadd function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518290/how-to-add-hours-to-current-date-in-sql-server

Comment: Hi Hasan, How would I use dateadd to split the shift like in the desired output example above?

Comment: Could you give more data from table?

Comment: How would you classify someone that starts before 10pm but finishes during the 10pm-7am shift window?  Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a list of all the shifts and join it to the list of employee hours.
Note that this is not limited to hours or minutes.  You can even keep the milliseconds.

```
create table EmpHours ( EmployeeID int, InTime datetime, OutTime datetime )

insert into EmpHours ( EmployeeID, InTime, OutTime ) values
( 1, '2018-08-10T21:00:00.000', '2018-08-11T09:00:00.000' ),
( 2, '2000-08-28T17:18:19.123', '2000-08-29T11:12:13.456' ),
( 2, '2000-12-31T16:00:00.555', '2001-01-01T12:44:55.444' ),
( 3, '2018-08-01T18:00:01.123', '2018-08-04T09:09:09.009' ),
( 4, '2018-08-10T09:00:00.000', '2018-08-10T17:00:00.000' ),
( 4, '2018-08-12T23:00:00.023', '2018-08-13T03:04:05.000' ),
( 5, '2018-08-10T17:00:00.017', '2018-08-10T23:08:08.008' ),
( 6, '2018-08-10T03:00:00.703', '2018-08-10T04:04:04.704' )

;
with 
-- Determine the earliest and latest dates.
-- Cast to date to remove the time portion.
-- Cast results back to datetime because we're going to add hours later.
MinMaxDates 
as 
(select cast(min(cast(InTime  as date))as datetime) as MinDate, 
        cast(max(cast(OutTime as date))as datetime) as MaxDate from EmpHours),

-- How many days have passed during that period
Dur
as
(select datediff(day,MinDate,MaxDate) as Duration from MinMaxDates),

-- Create a list of numbers.
-- These will be added to MinDate to get a list of dates.
-- We add a margin to deal with edge cases
NumList
as
( select -2 as Num
  union all
  select Num+1 from NumList,Dur where Num<=Duration+2 ),

-- Create a list of dates by adding those numbers to MinDate
DayList 
as
( select dateadd(day,Num,MinDate)as WorkDate from NumList, MinMaxDates  ),

-- Create a list of shifts starting on those dates
ShiftList
as
( select dateadd(hour, 7,WorkDate) as StartTime, -- from 7 AM to 10 PM
         dateadd(hour,22,WorkDate) as EndTime,
         'day' as [Type]
         from DayList
  union
  select dateadd(hour,22,WorkDate) as StartTime, -- from 10 PM to 7 AM of the next day
         dateadd(hour,31,WorkDate) as EndTime,
         'night' as [Type]
         from DayList  ),

-- Join the list of Shifts to the list of Employee Hours
EmpShiftList
as
( select * from ShiftList, EmpHours 
where InTime<=EndTime and OutTime>=StartTime
),

-- Keep the later   of the shift start time, and the employee in-time
-- Keep the earlier of the shift   end time, and the employee out-time
EmpShifts
as
( select EmployeeID, 
         case when InTime>=StartTime then InTime  else StartTime end as InTime,
         case when OutTime<=EndTime  then OutTime else EndTime   end as OutTime,
         [Type] from EmpShiftList)

-- List the results in order
-- Use MaxRecursion option in case there are more than 100 days 
select * from EmpShifts 
order by EmployeeID, InTime, OutTime
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Here's another way of doing it that doesn't use number lists or recursion.

Note:  On further consideration, the following code doesn't always give the same answer as the code above.  It fails if the period from InTime to OutTime is over several days. This might be an unlikely situation, but I consider it a bug. Try it with this input:

```
insert into EmpHours ( EmployeeID, InTime, OutTime ) values
( 7777, '2018-08-10T21:22:23.245', '2018-08-13T09:03:04.056' )
```

I'll leave it here for historic purposes, but I recommend the first version.

```
; -- *** DO NOT USE THIS VERSION *** See notes above. 
with 
-- Get list of dates from table
-- Cast to date to remove time portion
DayListA 
as
( select cast(InTime as date) as DateA from EmpHours
  union
  select cast(OutTime as date) as DateA from EmpHours
),
-- For each such date, add the preceding date.
-- This is to deal with shifts that start the previous day
DayListB
as
( select DateA as DateB from DayListA
  union
  select DateAdd(day,-1,DateA) as DateB from DayListA
),
-- Cast to datetime so we can add hours
-- Remove duplicates
DayList
as
( select distinct cast(DateB as datetime) as WorkDate from DayListB
),
-- Create a list of shifts starting on those dates
ShiftList
as
( select dateadd(hour, 7,WorkDate) as StartTime, -- from 7 AM to 10 PM
         dateadd(hour,22,WorkDate) as EndTime,
         'day' as [Type]
         from DayList
  union
  select dateadd(hour,22,WorkDate) as StartTime, -- from 10 PM to 7 AM of the next day
         dateadd(hour,31,WorkDate) as EndTime,
         'night' as [Type]
         from DayList  ),

-- Join the list of Shifts to the list of Employee Hours
EmpShiftList
as
( select * from ShiftList, EmpHours 
where InTime<=EndTime and OutTime>=StartTime
),

-- Keep the later   of the shift start time, and the employee in-time
-- Keep the earlier of the shift   end time, and the employee out-time
EmpShifts
as
( select EmployeeID, 
         case when InTime>=StartTime then InTime else StartTime end as InTime,
         case when OutTime<=EndTime then OutTime else EndTime end as OutTime,
         [Type] from EmpShiftList)

-- List the results in order
select * from EmpShifts 
order by EmployeeID, InTime, OutTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a bit of an example for you which does what you want, however it is quite inefficient.

It essentially uses a loop and will output what you want, but I would suggest investigating ways to make this more efficient if you're going to use it on a large scale.

I've added some comments below for you to read through in the code as well.

```
--DROP TABLE #data

SELECT 
    '1' as [Employee ID], 
    '2018-08-10 21:00:00.000' as [InTime], 
    '2018-08-11 09:00:00.000' as [OutTime]
INTO #data


DECLARE @MinDate datetime --Create variables used for the loop
DECLARE @MaxDate datetime
DECLARE @CurDate datetime
DECLARE @EmployeeID int

--Set the variables based off what is in the #data table
SELECT @MinDate = InTime,
       @MaxDate = Outtime,
       @EmployeeID = [Employee ID]
FROM #data

SET @CurDate = @MinDate

--DROP TABLE #datalines
--Create a table to insert lines into
CREATE TABLE #datalines
(   
    EmployeeID int,
    TheDate datetime,
    ShiftType NVARCHAR(10),
    ShiftTypeNo int
)

DECLARE @ShiftType NVARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @ShiftTypeNumber int = 0 --This is used for splitting out shifts betwen day & night for grouping later on

WHILE(dateadd(mi, 1, @CurDate) <= @maxdate) --While there is still minutes unaccounted for, loop through every minute between start & end
BEGIN
    IF(DATEPART(hour, @curDate) IN (22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6) AND @ShiftType != 'Night') --If we currently have not set the shift type, or it changes and is incorrect, then set it.
    BEGIN
        SET @ShiftTypeNumber = @ShiftTypeNumber + 1
        SET @ShiftType = 'Night' --If we are in the night hours, then set the shift type to night.
    END
    ELSE IF(DATEPART(hour, @curDate) NOT IN (22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6) AND @ShiftType != 'Day')
    BEGIN
        SET @ShiftTypeNumber = @ShiftTypeNumber + 1
        SET @ShiftType = 'Day' --If we are in the day hours, then set the shift type to day.
    END

    --Insert into our data table with the current date in minutes and what shift type and shift number it is
    INSERT INTO #datalines 
    SELECT @EmployeeID,@CurDate, @ShiftType, @ShiftTypeNumber

    --Add a minute to our date loop.
    SET @CurDate = dateadd(mi, 1, @CurDate) 
END

--Output the results
SELECT [EmployeeID],
       MIN([TheDate]) as [Start Shift],
       CASE 
            WHEN MAX([TheDate]) < @MaxDate THEN DATEADD(mi,1, MAX([TheDate])) ELSE MAX([TheDate]) END
        as [End Shift], --If it isn't the end of the shift, add 1 minute (otherwise it would show the hour before with 59 mins)
       [ShiftType]
FROM #datalines
GROUP BY [EmployeeID], 
         [ShiftType],
        [ShiftTypeNo]
ORDER BY [Start Shift]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate a list of hours between the minimum and maximum date/times. Then you can use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to group the records.

#### Example:

```
WITH
source_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, '10-Aug-2018 21:00', '10-Aug-2018 22:00')
    , ( 2, '10-Aug-2018 20:00', '11-Aug-2018 07:00')
    , ( 3, '11-Aug-2018 07:00', '11-Aug-2018 09:00')
    , ( 4, '10-Aug-2018 20:00', '11-Aug-2018 09:00')
    ) tbl ([EmployeeId], [InTime], [OutTime]) 
)
, 
source_data_dates
AS
(
    SELECT [InTimeMin] = MIN([InTime]), [OutTimeMax] = MAX([OutTime]) FROM source_data
)
,
source_data_times([n], [InTime]) 
AS
(
    SELECT 1, CAST([InTimeMin] AS DATETIME) FROM source_data_dates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1, [InTimeMin] = CAST(DATEADD(hh, n, [InTimeMin]) AS DATETIME)  FROM source_data_times, source_data_dates WHERE n <= DATEDIFF(hh, [InTimeMin], [OutTimeMax])
)
, 
source_data_times_type
AS
(
    SELECT
          [InTime] = [InTime]
        , [OutTime] = DATEADD(hh, 1, [InTime])
        , [Type] = 
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST([InTime] AS TIME) >= '22:00:00' OR CAST([InTime] AS TIME) < '07:00:00'
                THEN 'night'
                ELSE 'day'
            END
    FROM 
        source_data_times
)
, 
source_data_times_type_rank
AS
(
    SELECT 
          sd.[EmployeeId]
        , tt.[InTime]
        , tt.[OutTime]
        , tt.[Type]
        , [GroupRank] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.[EmployeeId] ORDER BY tt.[Type], CAST(tt.[InTime] AS DATE))
    FROM
        source_data AS sd
        INNER JOIN source_data_times_type AS tt ON tt.[InTime] >= sd.[InTime] AND tt.[InTime] < sd.[OutTime]
)
SELECT
      [EmployeeId]
    , [InTime] = MIN([InTime])
    , [OutTime] = MAX([OutTime])
    , [Type]
FROM 
    source_data_times_type_rank
GROUP BY 
      [EmployeeId]
    , [Type]
    , [GroupRank]
ORDER BY
      [EmployeeId]
    , MIN([InTime])
```

#### Results:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that all employees will arrive and leave at exactly the top of the hour?  Add some non-zero minutes or seconds, or even milliseconds to your inputs.

Comment: @DavidDubois, good point. I was just using the example from the question.