# Use yesterday date on where clause with specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to select a value using yesterdays date with a specific time. here is my example:
So I want to replace the yesterday variable with the date of yesterday but specify in specific time.

```
select Flow, Sum(Morning) Morning, Sum(PM) PM, Sum(Night) Night, Count(*) Total
from [dbo].[MISSION]
cross apply (values (Iif(QUELLE in ('Réception_14','Réception_21'),'Flow 1',
                        Iif(QUELLE in ('Réception_17','Réception_16'),'Flow 2','Flow3'))))f(Flow)
cross apply (values ( Convert(time, [START_DATE] )))v(T)
cross apply (
    select
        case when T >= **YESTERDAYDATE:'06:00:00'** and T < **YESTERDAYDATE:'11:00:00'** then 1 else 0 end Morning,
        case when T >=**YESTERDAYDATE:'11:00:00'** and T < **YESTERDAYDATE:'22:00:00'** then 1 else 0 end PM,
        case when T >=**YESTERDAYDATE:'22:00:00'** and T < **YESTERDAYDATE:'06:00:00'** then 1 else 0 end Night
)c
group by Flow
```

Thanks

Comment: Some things don't add up here: you are comparing a `time` value to a `datetime`. Also you clearly know how to use `cross apply (values` to store intermediate calculations, you can use the same technique with `dateadd(day, -1, getdate())`. So what exactly is the question?

Comment: the  question is how can I add the specific time on the date the yesterday date ? YESTERDAYDATE:06:00:00

Comment: Again `dateadd(hour, 6, yesterdaysdate)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add hours to current date in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518290/how-to-add-hours-to-current-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: Aside... if you're measuring 24 hour periods between 6am on one day and 6am on the next then `and T < **YESTERDAYDATE:'06:00:00'**` should be today's date, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cast or convert your `START_DATE` to time or you will not be able to make comparison like `T >= **YESTERDAYDATE:'06:00:00'`

```
cross apply 
(
    values ( [START_DATE] )
) v (T)
```

You need yesterday and today's date at midnight `00:00:00`

```
cross apply
(   
    values (convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())),
            convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate() - 1)))
) dates (today, yesterday)
```

And with the above, you can obtain the various datetime like `YESTERDAYDATE:'06:00:00'`, `YESTERDAYDATE:'22:00:00'`

```
cross apply
(
    values (dateadd(hour, 6, yesterday), 
            dateadd(hour, 11, yesterday), 
            dateadd(hour, 22, yesterday), 
            dateadd(hour, 6, today))
) dt (y6, y11, y22, t6)
```

and then finally

```
cross apply 
(
    select  case when T >= y6  and T < y11 then 1 else 0 end Morning,
            case when T >= y11 and T < y22 then 1 else 0 end PM,
            case when T >= y22 and T < t6  then 1 else 0 end Night
) c
```

Note : The last `CASE` expression `Night` should be from yesterday `22:00` till today `06:00`